Problema al usar herencia y headers en c++
soy nuevo usando headers y estoy tratando de hacer un ejemplo de herencia con headers. Lo que hice fue declarar los elementos de la clase "Persona" en el header y luego implementar los métodos y constructores en un "Persona.cpp".
Luego de hacer eso, intenté crear un nuevo archivo cpp de la clase que quería que heredara de "Persona" llamado "Estudiante.cpp" y importé el header de persona. Hay un error del compilador que dice "undefined reference to `Persona::mostrarPersona()'"
//persona.h
#ifndef PERSONA_H
#define PERSONA_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Persona{
   private:
   string nombre;
   int edad;
   public:
   Persona(string, int);
   void mostrarPersona();
};
#endif

//persona.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include"persona.h"
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;


Persona::Persona(string _nombre, int _edad){
   nombre = _nombre;
   edad = _edad;
}
void Persona::mostrarPersona(){
   cout << "Nombre: " << nombre<< endl;
   cout << "Edad: " << edad <<endl;
}

//estudiante.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include"persona.h"
using namespace std;

class Estudiante : public Persona{
   private:
   string codigoAlumno; 
   float notaFinal;
   public:
   Estudiante(string, int,string, float);
   void mostrarEstudiante();
};

Estudiante::Estudiante(string _nombre, int _edad,
                        string _codigoDeAlumno, float _nota) : Persona(_nombre, _edad){
   codigoAlumno = _codigoDeAlumno;
   notaFinal = _nota;
}
void Estudiante::mostrarEstudiante(){
   mostrarPersona();
   cout << "Codigo alumno: " << codigoAlumno << endl << "Nota final: " << notaFinal << endl;
}

int main()
{
   Estudiante e1 = Estudiante("Alejandro", 24, "113456", 6.1 );
   e1.mostrarEstudiante();
   return 0;
}


Los 3 elementos están en una misma carpeta

Compila tu programa con g++ -o programa persona.cpp estudiante.cpp -I. y debería funcionar, o crea un makefile que use ambos ficheros fuente para generar tu programa

Cómo compilas el programa? El error sugiere que no está encontrando la función mostrarPersona, probablemente porque no estás compilando persona.cpp

Si la compilación deja de funcionar de un momento para el otro, puedes probar a borrar la carpeta .vscode y el archivo cpp-algo-mas.json para restablecer la configuración.
